# Let $A$ be a PID, $M$ an injective finitely generated module. Prove that $M = 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, finitely-generated, injective-module

Help!

Let $A$ be a PID, $M$ an injective finitely generated module.

Prove that:

$$ M = 0.$$

Comment: People will be much more motivated to help if you indicate what you have tried. In particular when it is phrased like this (imparative is usually not well-received).

Comment: Also the statement looks wrong to me. Take $A$ a field, then any finitely generated vector space is injective, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: To avoid close votes, take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on how to ask a good question, and more particularly [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) for providing extra content such as what you understand and have tried, and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) for avoiding "I haven't got a clue!" questions.

Answer (score 2):

As $A$ is a PID and $M$ is finitely generated, by the structure theorem of finitely generated modules over a PID we have that 
$$M\cong A^r\oplus\bigoplus_{i=1}^k A/(p_i^{\alpha_i})$$
for some $r,\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and some prime elements $p_i\in A$. So you may assume that $M$ is equal to the module in the right.

Now, an injective module must be divisible: for the proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183321/injective-group-is-divisible) and just change $\mathbb{Z}$ by $A$ accordingly (actually, a module is injective iff it is divisible in a PID but this is not used here).

Hence, for each $a\in A$ the map 
$$\begin{align*} a\cdot:M&\rightarrow M \\ f&\mapsto a\cdot f \end{align*}$$
is surjective.

This imply that $\alpha_i=0$ for each $i$. Otherwise the map $p_i\cdot$ wouldn't be surjective, because an element in the image of $p_i\cdot$ would always have a $0$ in its $i$-coordinate.

Hence, $M=A^r$. But if the multiplication by $a\cdot$ is surjective then $a$ is invertible (look at the first coordinate of an element in the inverse of $(1,0,\cdots,0)$). Hence every element in $a$ is invertible and $A$ is a field.

So your result is true only if you assume that your ring is not a field as noticed by Severin Schraven in the comments.